# Display some new products being created at the top of the product list page

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

We have a requirement where we have to display some newly created products at the top of the product list page.
What approach to use here?Should we change Solr query to sort the products by creation time or introduce a Solr sort or make changes in Java code?

Answer (score 1):

You can check boost rules. You need to use product attribute for **new** then boost it. Maybe you need new cronjob for removing **new** attribute from to old product.

Answer (score 0):

You can set those products as hero products from back-office manually or you can create [boost rules](https://help.hybris.com/1808/hcd/8b6c752f86691014aaf59276abe831ed.html) based on the attribute `creation time`.